# Manga with a cursed green-haired weapon smith

Tags: story-identification, manga, sword-and-sorcery

I'm looking for a fantasy manga where a young green-haired weapon smith gets cursed and gets hunted by the kingdom’s army and his red-hair soldier friend.

The kingdom is closed off and there are a bunch of zealots about the curses of evil magic users.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Are the zealots supporting the evil magic-users, or are they opposed to them?

Comment: During the pandemic and on the Mangakakalot website. The Kingdom’s people are zealots who oppose the evil magic users. That’s why the Green-hair MC is being harrassed & hunted

Comment: Ah, I think I get it.  They're harassing him _because_ he's been cursed.  They're zealots because they're so opposed to the magic-users that they even blame their victims.  Is that basically correct?

Comment: Yes, that is what happened in the story.

Comment: Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: The manga was mostly black and white.

Comment: its this or no? The Strongest Swordsman Has Zero Equipment Slots, but He Can Equip up to 9999 Items if It’s Cursed . theres also My S-Rank Party Fired Me for Being a Cursificer ~ I Can Only Make “Cursed Items”, but They’re Artifact Class!